# i2c master for s35390a rtc slave

Tags: i2c

Is there a sample i2c master code that supports rtc s35390a hardware clock? I am currently working on an SOC that needs to support s35390a from Seiko. But currently, i am getting an error *rtc-s35390a 0-0030: hctosys: unable to read the hardware clock*. I cannot read/write data properly. I am implementing combined form of transmission.

Answer (score -1):

Use oscilloscope to check if I2C SCL/SDA show some thing

If you can get the first address correct waveform, You will easy to get the register value

This might not be a rtc chip problem.